# Entendimento de sintaxe pl/sql Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, sintaxe, pl-sql

Tenho uma PROC Oracle 11g. Dentro da proc tem algo assim:

```
v_prazo_subs_ans         ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema.val_parametro%type;
```

Onde:

`v_prazo_subs_ans` é uma variável

`ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema` é a tabela

`val_parametro` um campo na tabela

Porém eu não sei o que significa isso:
`%type` após o nome do campo.

O que a linha supra citada faz ou quer dizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este %Type cria uma variável com o mesmo Type (tipo e tamanho) do campo passado , no caso val_parametro da tabela ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema , a vantagem desta chamada e que se o tipo ou o tamanho forem alterados a variável é alterada automaticamente na próxima execução da rotina evitando erros do tipo truncamento ou de tipos.

Exemplo clássico um campo que era VARCHAR2(30) precisou passar para VARCHAR2(40) com a chamada por "%type" os objetos assim defidos não precisam ser revistos.